# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined from Deode/Encode Stream Bundle.js not from my code

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, buffer, tsx

I got a lot of problem trying to get my npm project updated at webpack 5 and now i only have one error that stands  :

```
bundle.js:1088566 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at bundle.js:1044980:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1045039:4)
    at ./node_modules/restructure/src/DecodeStream.js (bundle.js:1045041:4)
    at options.factory (bundle.js:1089181:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:1088563:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:1088838:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1045071:18)
    at ./node_modules/restructure/src/EncodeStream.js (bundle.js:1045193:4)
    at options.factory (bundle.js:1089181:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:1088563:33)
```

OR

```
bootstrap:27 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at DecodeStream.js:31:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (DecodeStream.js:98:1)
    at ./node_modules/restructure/src/DecodeStream.js (DecodeStream.js:102:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (EncodeStream.js:9:1)
    at ./node_modules/restructure/src/EncodeStream.js (EncodeStream.js:151:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.9.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.4.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.9",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.21",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.9.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.40.1",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.4",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.2.1",
    "react-google-places-autocomplete": "^3.3.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-jsx-parser": "^1.29.0",
    "react-pdf-html": "^1.1.8",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.3",
    "react-sketch-canvas": "^6.1.0",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "react-zlib-js": "^1.0.5",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^2.1.3",
    "recharts": "^2.1.5",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.3",
    "@types/draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "@types/draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^0.38.0",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.4",
    "@types/react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.8",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

And here  my webpack config :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
///

    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "path": false,
        "stream": false,
      },
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [

        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshRuntimeEntry,
          reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntryHelpers,
          babelRuntimeRegenerator,
        ]),
      ],
    },
```

I already tried to add this plugin to webpack config but it doesn't work it make a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets') at Compilation.createModuleAssets`  :

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        }),
```

I also already tried to add  `"buffer": false`, in fallback but no changes

I also already tried to comment the lines / erase the file at  ./node_modules/restructure/src/DecodeStream.js  but nothing change

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Downgrading my node version to 15.14 worked by doing a npm i again didn't got any error, tho the project is really outdated now...